# What's the standard for percentages in Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been looking all over, and really just need  a definitive answer to ride on. I'm going to have an object that contains percentages compiled from other objects, the point here is, what's the standard for representing a percentage in rails, without it getting broken in data migrations and things like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `:decimal` as the type, they'll get converted into `BigDecimal`s.  Be sure to specify `:precision` and `:scale` in your migration, lest Rails decide that you really wanted an integer instead.

Comment: So for a percentage field that I want to have a maximum of 1.00 (eg 100%) then scale=2(eg for .00), do I set precision as 3?

Comment: For others who come here wondering, Precision is the total amount of digits, scale is the number of digits right of the decimal point